# Do docker-compose's two `command` forms behave differently?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In Dockerfile, we can specify the `CMD` to be in one of three different forms:

> ...
>
> - `CMD ["executable","param1","param2"]` (*exec* form, this is the preferred form)
> - `CMD ["param1","param2"]` (*as default parameters to ENTRYPOINT*)
> - `CMD command param1 param2` (*shell* form)
>
> ...
>
> If you use the shell form of the `CMD`, then the `<command>` will execute in `/bin/sh -c`:
>
> ```
> FROM ubuntu
> CMD echo "This is a test." | wc -
> ```
>
> If you want to run your `<command>` without a shell then you must express the command as a JSON array and give the full path to the executable. This array form is the preferred format of `CMD`. Any additional parameters must be individually expressed as strings in the array:
>
> ```
> FROM ubuntu
> CMD ["/usr/bin/wc","--help"]
> ```
>
> [**Source**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

In docker-compose, we can also use two different forms for its `command`:

> ...
>
> Override the default command.
>
> ```
> command: bundle exec thin -p 3000
> ```
>
> The command can also be a list, in a manner similar to dockerfile:
>
> ```
> command: ["bundle", "exec", "thin", "-p", "3000"]
> ```
>
> [**Source**](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command)

**Do these two different forms in docker-compose behave the same way as the *exec* and *shell* forms in Dockerfile do?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they do not. docker-compose's `command` always uses the equivalent of Dockerfile's *exec* form. This can be easily seen with a quick demo:

Dockerfile with *shell* form processes shell symbols:

```
FROM alpine:3.11.5
CMD echo foo && echo bar
```

```
$ docker run example
foo
bar
```

Dockerfile with *exec* form doesn't do any shell processing:

```
FROM alpine:3.11.5
CMD ["echo", "foo", "&&", "echo", "bar"]
```

```
$ docker run example
foo && echo bar
```

docker-compose's first command form doesn't do any shell processing:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  example:
    image: alpine:3.11.5
    command: echo foo && echo bar
```

```
$ docker-compose up
Starting example_example_1 ... done
Attaching to example_example_1
example_1  | foo && echo bar
example_example_1 exited with code 0
```

And neither does docker-compose's second command form:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  example:
    image: alpine:3.11.5
    command: ["echo", "foo", "&&", "echo", "bar"]
```

```
$ docker-compose up
Starting example_example_1 ... done
Attaching to example_example_1
example_1  | foo && echo bar
example_example_1 exited with code 0
```

---

So, if one does want shell processing in docker-compose's `command`, it has to be explicitly enabled by passing the command to `sh -c`:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  example:
    image: alpine:3.11.5
    command: sh -c "echo foo && echo bar"
```

```
$ docker-compose up
Starting example_example_1 ... done
Attaching to example_example_1
example_1  | foo
example_1  | bar
example_example_1 exited with code 0
```

Comment: If your second sentence appeared in the docs, I would have saved a couple of hours today. Came to same conclusion eventually, but this is a really solid answer.